# Login on a website via Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I would like some help for my project. I need to get informations on a forum (medical questions) `http://www.safeboy.net/club/index.php?`.

But I have a problem, for those informations, I need to be connected on the forum.

But I'm new in Jsoup and I didn't know well Jsoup, so I'm here to have some help, if you could advice me it'll be nice !

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup //
            .connect("http://www.safeboy.net/club/club.php?") //
            .method(Method.GET) //
            .execute();

Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.safeboy.net/club/club.php?")
                    .data("pseudo", "EDDFSB")
                    .data("password", "cacapopo1").method(Method.POST)
                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                    .post();

    System.out.println(document);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the call to `followRedirect()`. After the POST the server sends a redirect to the client (HTTP 302 code).

```
Document document = Jsoup //
        .connect("http://www.safeboy.net/club/club.php?") //
        .data("pseudo", "EDDFSB") //
        .data("password", "cacapopo1") //
        .method(Method.POST) //
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies()) //
        .followRedirects(true) //
        .post();
```

The member zone is organized with a frameset. You'll have to ask Jsoup to download each frame of frameset before getting information.